# insert tag property string in hyperlink title attribute in struts2

Tags: attributes, hyperlink, struts2, properties, title

I have a small problem, how can I place a tag property string to show as a title in a hyperlink?

my code:

```
<a href="<s:property value="picurl" />" rel="shadowbox" title="<s:property value='title'/>" ><img id="scale-mid-high" src="<s:property value="picurl" title="maximize" />"   align="left"/></a>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean as long as there is a getter on you action called getWhatever you should be able to say <s:property value="whatever"/>, you don't even need a getter you could just make the field public.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<s:url namespace='someNameSpace' action='someAction'">
    <s:property value="whatever"/>
</a>
```

Is one method but could use the

```
<s:a>
```

tag... I forget why but I generally go with what I listed above I found I needed to replace them because of some requirement.

For more details on both

```
<s:url> and 
<s:a>
```

http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1.1/docs/tag-reference.html where there is an example with most of the tags and all the possible properties are explained.